# Lerp() function not working as desired in construct 2

Tags: math, 2d-games, construct-2

I want to create and effect of distributing cards in a construct 2 game. I have a starting position (500,215) from where cards are distributed. There are 6 players in game and each player will have 5 cards. I have an array of positions where each card object should go. I have been trying to achieve this using lerf() function, but it doesn't work.

My implementation of lerp() function [can be found here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF8Uc.png) Are there any other ways to achieve this in construct 2? I want to make something that does following in construct 2,

Move card from A(500, 215) to Position(0) in array - take 1 sec to move from initial position to destination position.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use Lerp for move cards, then you may use MoveTo behavior.
It is easy and performance way for moving objects.

[Rex MoveTo Behavior](https://rexrainbow.github.io/C2RexDoc/repo/rex_moveto.7z)

[Rex MoveTo Docs](https://c2rexplugins.weebly.com/rex_moveto.html)